# Linking a .css file with a markdown .doc

Tags: css, r, r-markdown

Im trying to use some .css in my Rmarkdown file. Therefore I created a notepad file with the following text:

```
#nextsteps {
color: blue;
}  

.emphasized {
font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

And saved it as styles.css

After this I created an .Rmd file in the same folder with the following code:

```
---
title: "test2"
output: html_document
 theme: null
 highlight: null
 css: styles.css
 ---

 ## Next Steps {#nextsteps}
```

When I try to knit it I get the following error however:

```
 Error in yaml::yaml.load(enc2utf8(string), ...) : 
 Scanner error: mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 3, column 9
 Calls: <Anonymous> ... yaml_load_utf8 -> mark_utf8 -> <Anonymous> -> .Call
 Execution halted
```

Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

Comment: your yaml is faulty. add a new line after `output:` with `html_document:` indented two spaces, then indent the following options four spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatting matters with yaml.

```
---
title: "test2"
output: 
  html_document:
    theme: null
    highlight: null
    css: styles.css
---
```